# How can I create a DateTime for a specific time with the correct UTC offset in an SP2013 workflow in VS?

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, date-time

I'm trying to pause a workflow until 8 AM on a specific day.

I am on the East Coast of the US: UTC -5.

I can create a `DateTime` object with a time of 8 AM like this:

```
new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Day, 8, 0, 0)
```

And then set it to the correct day by doing

```
DateTime.AddDays(daysToAdd)
```

However, even if I create it with the optional `Kind` parameter of `DateTimeKind.Local`, when I log the time I see that the time is actually set to 8 AM (no time zone offset).

I know that the offset needs to be there, because if I pause the workflow by doing something like:

```
DateTime pauseUntil = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinute(15.0)
```

I can see that the `pauseUntil` has the time zone offset included (i.e. my local time is 1 PM, but the logged value of `pauseUntil` is 18:00), so I know that for the workflow to really pause until 8 AM local time, the `DateTime` object should have a time of 13:00.  But I can't seem to find a way to convert it within the workflow.

Here are some things that **do not** work in workflows:

```
DateTime.ToLocalTime()
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(myOriginalDateTime)
new DateTimeOffset(myOriginalDateTime).LocalDateTime
```

So how can I do the conversion?  I know I could brute-force it by creating a DateTime object with hour 13, but that won't account for daylight savings time...